# Python: Convert simplejson dumped unicode datetime back to datetime object

Tags: python, json, datetime, unicode, simplejson

I have...

```
entity = simplejson.dumps({"a":unicode(datetime.datetime.utcnow())})
```

How do I convert the datetime (that was converted to unicode) back to datetime again?

So that I can do something like...

```
entity2 = simplejson.loads(entity)
#your answer here..
add5 = entity2["a"] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Do the following before serializing:

```
time = datetime.strftime(time, DATETIME_FORMAT)
```

Do the following after unserializing:

```
time = datetime.strptime(time, DATETIME_FORMAT)
```

example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

>>> time = datetime.now()
>>> time
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 5, 3, 1, 45, 646302)

>>> time = time.strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)
>>> time
'2011-05-05 03:01:45'

>>> import json

>>> time = json.loads(json.dumps(time))
>>> time
'2011-05-05 03:01:45'

>>> time = datetime.strptime(time, DATETIME_FORMAT)
>>> time
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 5, 3, 1, 45)
```

In case you find this somewhat inelegant, you might consider a custom json encoder/decoder. I personally have tried the ones in the default json package, but gave up pulling my hair out with cryptic error messages. If you go this path, I might recommend a third party json package.

Comment: Hey we tied! Although I admit your answer is constructed better than mine.

Comment: eh, you thought of it right away =) I had to go digging through my old code to find it =\

Comment: Yeah I just had to mess around with this in a reservation system I wrote for a client.

Answer (score 2):

Use [datetime.datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(entity2['a'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: it does support microseconds as `%f` =) see http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Oh yeah you are totally right! I thought that was odd, well so much for reading comprehension at 2:45am.